# Avoiding all system messages and messages from other software

Tags: c, windows

Here is the situation. The company I work for builds this piece of software in c that can make a Windows computer act a bit like a TV. Essentially, our piece of software is meant to be played full screen and content is displayed from the internet without the user having to ever touch the computer again.

The problem is that once in a while, the system brings up pop-ups like "Your Windows system is ready for an upgrade." or "Please renew your Norton subscription" etc. which the user has to periodically and manually remove.

Is there a way to display content full screen without being bothered by those warnings?

Comment: Hmya, these messages are Very Important.  To consider your app to be Most Important is a battle that's hard to win.  It is also rather questionable to suppress the "Motherboard is on fire" notificaiton.  You'll have to convince Windows that the user is actively using the window.  Kinda hard with a TV app.  You could generate some fake input with the SendInput() function.

Comment: Lol, I didn't know there was a "Motherboard is on fire" notification

Comment: You could test it with a blow torch.

Comment: Are you talking about baloon notifications? If you are using xp they can be easily disabled, see here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729. I believe that for specialist software you need to disable them in the settings menu for that app.

Comment: I'm talking about all notifications, including balloon notifications.

Comment: A possible approach to not have to fight the previously mentioned "battle" might be to somehow trick windows to think the actual screen it could use to place it's ballons and requesters is much larger then the physically screen available. Having done so successfully, one only needs to make the most quiet part of the screen (typically the upperleft corner) the viewable part and then move one's peacefull window (sized to the physical screen size) up there to be able to have an undisturbed pleasure of viewing.

Comment: Why do you have malware like Norton installed on the system? Just set the legitimate things that update (like Windows Update) to run automatically but never reboot automatically, and uninstall the illegitimate ones (like Norton).

Comment: @Kenneth: [Balloon notifications **do not** steal focus from a full-screen application (even if it might seem like it).](http://superuser.com/questions/244944/balloon-notifications-make-xbmc-minimize-from-full-screen/249047#249047)  Disabling balloons won't really help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yah, whether or not the development community agrees, Microsoft has several standards for when and why it might be acceptable to have exclusive use of the monitor.

The most official strategy is to use DirectX in exclusive mode. This is what games do, what windows media player does in full screen video with hardware acceleration enabled, etc... **If your application is multimedia intensive (*as suggested by TV like functionality*), you should probably be using DirectX** too. Besides giving you the exclusive display access it will also increase your applications performance while lowering the CPU load (as it will overload graphics work to the video card when possible).

If DirectX is not an option, there are a great number of hacks available that seem to all behave differently between various generations of windows operating systems. So you might have to be prepared to implement several techniques to cover each OS you plan to support.

One technique is to set your application as the currently running screensaver. A screensaver if really just an EXE renamed to SCR with certain command line switches it should support. But you can write your own application to be such a screensaver and a little launcher stub that sets it as the screensaver and launches it. Upon exit the application should return the original screensaver settings (perhaps the launcher waits for the process to exit so that it returns the settings in both graceful exits and any unplanned process terminations ie: app crash). I'm not sure if this behavior is consistent across platforms though, you'll have to test it.

Preventing other applications from creating window handles is truly a hack in my opinion and pretty bad one that I wouldn't appreciate as a customer of such software.

A constant `BringWindowToTop()` call to keep you in front is better (it doesn't break other software) but still a little hack-ish.

Answer (score 7):

Catch window creation messages with a global hook. This way you can close or hide unwanted windows before they become visible.

**EDIT:** If you definitely want to avoid hooks, then you can call a function periodically, which puts your window to the top of the z-stack.

Comment: I feel that such kind of hook is a bit overkill... :S

Comment: I had the same problem a few years ago, and could not find any simpler method. It is especially ugly that you must use a DLL for the code of the global hook.

Answer (score 4):

You could disable system updates http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901037 and remove the norton malware.

You could also connect a second screen so that the bubbles appear in the the first monitor.

Or you rewrite it for linux or windows ce.

One final option is to install software that reconfigures your os into a kiosk http://shop.inteset.com/Products/9-securelockdown.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need keyboard or mouse input, how about running your application as a [screensaver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144066%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of thoses messages are trigged/managed by Windows Explorer.
Just replace it with your dummy c#/winform.
By changing the registry value

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="Explorer.exe"
```

You can specify virtually any exe as an alternative to explorer.exe
That's the way all windows based (embedded) system (ATM & co) do.
There's still few adjustment (disable services you dont need / dr watson & others), and of course, you'll want to keep a "restart explorer.exe" backdoor.
But that's a good start

Comment: Going this way, you'll get specific and efficient support from Microsoft directly (if you need), and mostly, that don't involve any dirty hacks.

Comment: The windows update messages might be triggered by explorer, but definitely not 3rd party "toasts". Aside from the mentioned Norton there could be MS Outlook, google talk, msn messanger, etc... As a C# developer myself, I even create my own toast messages in some of my apps which are not dependent on explorer. I suppose my assumption above is that this was a consumer app and not an embedded device or they might as well license an embedded operating system from Microsoft such as XP embedded. This is a stripped down version of windows intended exactly for your suggestion as a dedicated device.